# Finite simple groups that all of their proper non-abelian simple sections are isomorphic to either A5, PSL(2,7) or PSL(2,9)

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I know that by a result of Blyth and Robinson published in 1995, all finite simple groups that all of their proper non-abelian simple sections are isomorphic to one of the simple groups A5 or PSL(2,7) are characterized. I am looking for a characterization of all finite simple groups that all of their proper non-abelian simple sections are isomorphic to one of the simple groups A5, PSL(2,7) or PSL(2,9).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What might such a characterization look like, roughly?

Comment: The Blyth-Robinson 1995 paper, published in Comm. Algebra, is [here behind paywall (DOI link)](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927879508825338). It might be useful to describe the characterization. (I'd expect some kind of composition series of bounded length — with an explicit bound, independent of the group— in which blocks are either solvable or semisimple??)

Comment: **semi**-simple?

Comment: @markvs for a finite group I'd (somewhat abusively) use "semisimple" as "direct product of finite non-abelian simple groups".

Comment: But you can get examples with arbitrarily large  semisimple length by taking iterated wreath products of $A_5$. I am still unsure of what sort of general description one might expect of this class of groups.

Answer (score 5):

I think that this problem can be broken down to a relatively transparent residual case. If $G$ is such a group, you can only hope to control the structure of $G/{\rm Sol}(G)$, where ${\rm Sol}(G)$ is the largest solvable normal subgroup of $G$, and you can also only hope to control the structure of $G^{(\infty)}$, the terminal member of the derived series of $G$. Hence we only consider perfect groups $G$ with ${\rm Sol}(G) = 1.$

Then $F^{\ast}(G)$ is a direct product of simple groups, each isomorphic to one of ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$, ${\rm PSL}(2,9)$ or $A_{5}.$ Furthermore, $G/F^{\ast}(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Out}(F^{\ast}(G)).$ Since the structure of this outer automorphism group is reasonably transparent, it should be possible to continue to pin down the structure of $G$.

Later edit: This answer applies to the question originally asked.

Comment: Dear Prof. Robinson, thank you very much for your answer. Applogiz, I edited my question. I asked my question for finite "simple" groups. How do you think about simple groups with the above property?

Comment: This is a striking example where the failure of writing the question properly drastically changes its meaning.

Comment: @YCor, Yes you are right. Sorry for this, but it was a careless and a typo in my question.